# Visual Studio 2015 Remote Debugger 'not implemented'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, azure, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting crazy with Visual Stusio 2015 remote debugger.

**What I want:**

I have running a .Net console application on a Azure VM.
I want to remote debug my application and make some performance measure.

**What I've done so far:**

Application was compiled in debug mode and is running on the remote machine.
Over the Server-Explorer of VS2015 I added the Remote Debugger extention to the VM. Firewall on the VM is down for testing. Tested on two devices with the same result.

**What I get:**

I select my VM over the Server-Explorer and choose 'Attach debugger'.
I select my process of my running application (yes all processes running are shown).
Then after a few seconds I get the great error window 'Not implemented'!?

**Where I need help:**

Does anybody have a similar problem? Where can I find an error log to get more information on whats going on?

**Further**

I also created a Connect entry for this (Thanks for the hint @Vova). So if you have the same problem you can upvote it. [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1882818/visual-studio-2015-remote-debugger-not-implemented)

I'm thanksfull for every help. Greetings Steffen

[image: Undefined error]

Comment: Did you look through this link? https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ff683670.aspx#Anchor_3

Comment: @Vova yes thats all the steps I'm followed up.

Comment: Probably a bug in Visual Studio or Azure Debugging tools. Try to post this to Microsoft Connect...

Comment: did you actually publish your Azure project in the Debug build configuration? This isn't the default option, and you definitely *cannot* attach the remote debugger to an app in release build configuration.....

Comment: It is not publish as Azure Service. It's a simple console application running on a Azrue VM. But yes ist compiled in debug mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Microsoft Connect guy (Eliver) its a bug. It only effects Visual Studio 2015 with display language other then english.

**Solution 1**

Wait for next Azure SDK release with fix inside

**Solution 2**

Install english language pack from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=48157) and switch ths VS language to english from option dialog.

**Update - 2015-11-21**

I just wanted to let you know that the Azure SDK 2.8 has been released and this bug I'am facing have been resolved in this.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/announcing-the-azure-sdk-2-8-for-net/